# Assign Javascript var value through html input

Tags: javascript, html, input, getelementbyid, var

I am trying to make an interface where two player can submit their names before they start a game.
The html code is:

```
<div id="name-submit">

    <div id="name-submit-text">
        <p>
            Hello! Before you start playing, enter you names:
        </p>
    </div>

            <!--Review the whole name submission thing... Not working...-->

    <div id="p1-name-submit">
        <input id="p1-name-input">
    </div>

    <div id="name-submit-separation">
    </div>

    <div id="p2-name-submit">
        <input id="p2-name-input">
    </div>

    <button id="name-submit-button" onclick="hideNameSubmit()">Go!</button>

</div>
```

then the JS is:

```
var player1 = new Object();
  player1.name = "-";

var player2 = new Object();
  player2.name = "-";

function hideNameSubmit() {
var nameSubmitDiv = document.getElementById("name-submit");

player1.name = document.getElementById("p1-name-input").value;
player2.name = document.getElementById("p2-name-input").value;

nameSubmitDiv.style.display = 'none';
};
```

When I click the Go! button, the div disappears as it should, but the variables are not updated on the page.
I don't know what is causing this (I also have "p1-name and "p2-name" elements on the page, which are linked to the script with getElementById methods)...
Does anyone have an idea? If you need to see more of my code let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: "but the variables are not updated on the page" - not sure what you meant here? I don't see the code updating anything in the DOM

Comment: How are you checking that it is/isn't being saved?

Comment: You aren't doing anything special with the input values??

Comment: Do some debugging. Instead of `player1.name = document.getElementById("p1-name-input").value;` do `alert(document.getElementById("p1-name-input").value);` and see what is inside the alert.

Comment: Ivan Nevostruev, when I say the variables are not being updated on the page, I mean that the JS values of p1.name and p2.name, which are both "-" when the game hasn't started yet, should switch to whatever names are put in the input fields, for example "Ivan" and "Sam". When I tested using prompt boxes to assign names instead of the way i am trying now, the values updated fine on the html, but not anymore...

Comment: Gary Johnson, I will try that thanks for the advice, will keep you updated

Comment: Where does the JavaScript sit? Is it embedd in the page, or referenced in a file?